# Column wise report with sum values: MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

[Created table in this pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Zum.png)

Here, I have created a table with list of products with various companies along with price. Now, am trying to get company wise report in L1_cname, L2_cname & L3_cname with sum of prices. As shown in in below image..

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXIPU.png)

The output should be expected as below with sum of these prices with respective to Companies A,B & C.... Help me with the desired Output what am missing.....

Query....

```
SELECT L1_cname as L1Company,
SUM(CASE WHEN L1_cname = 'Company A' THEN L1_price ELSE L1_price END ) AS L1_Total_Price, 
SUM(CASE WHEN L2_cname = 'Company A' THEN L2_price ELSE L2_price END ) AS L2_Total_Price, 
SUM(CASE WHEN L3_cname = 'Company A' THEN L3_price ELSE L3_price END ) AS L3_Total_Price,
SUM((CASE WHEN L1_cname = 'Company A' THEN L1_price ELSE L1_price END )+
(CASE WHEN L2_cname = 'Company A' THEN L2_price ELSE L2_price END )+
(CASE WHEN L3_cname = 'Company A' THEN L3_price ELSE L3_price END )) as Baggage_Price 
FROM test_pricing ;
```

Comment: Please give data as text.

Comment: id Product L1_cname L1_price L2_cname L2_price L3_cname L3_price CreatedDate

1 Product_1 Company A 100 Company B 200 Company C 300 21-03-2022 10:11

2 Product_2 Company B 100 Company A 200 Company C 300 21-03-2022 10:11

3 Product_3 Company C 100 Company B 200 Company A 300 21-03-2022 10:11

4 Product_4 Company A 100 Company C 200 Company A 300

Comment: For Further details :Once please go through the links of images on the post...

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you have another table where you have a list of companies that could exist in the table. I have created a table to use for the example. We then join onto the table test_pricing three times, once for each column so as to be able to GROUP BY company.
See the dbFiddle link at the bottom for the schema and further testing.

> ```
> SELECT
>   compName,
>   COALESCE(SUM(L1.L1_price),0) L1_Total_Price,
>   COALESCE(SUM(L2.L2_price),0) L2_Total_Price,
>   COALESCE(SUM(L3.L3_price),0) L3_Total_Price,
>   COALESCE(SUM(L1.L1_price),0) 
>     + COALESCE(SUM(L2.L2_price),0) 
>     + COALESCE(SUM(L3.L3_price),0) Baggage_Price
> FROM companies c
> LEFT JOIN test_pricing L1 ON c.compName= L1.L1_cname
> LEFT JOIN test_pricing L2 ON c.compName= L2.L2_cname
> LEFT JOIN test_pricing L3 ON c.compName= L3.L3_cname
> GROUP BY compName
> ```
>
> ```
> compName  | L1_Total_Price | L2_Total_Price | L3_Total_Price | Baggage_Price
> :-------- | -------------: | -------------: | -------------: | ------------:
> Company A |            400 |            800 |           1200 |          2400
> Company B |            200 |            400 |              0 |           600
> Company C |            200 |            400 |            600 |          1200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b058dd6196eb9c7ecc1d86e0d3f2e937)*

Comment: Perfect - Please accept ou up vote the answer. Thank you